# Make my java swing animation smoother in Linux

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, animation, smoothing

Well I'm following this [tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/apprenez-a-programmer-en-java/le-fil-rouge-une-animation) to create my own animation and when I run it everything works well on Windows but in Ubuntu 17.04 the animation is smooth only if the mouse is moving over the app window. If don't it works like " in fits and starts" (I think is a good translation).
here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame {

private Panel pan = new Panel();
private JButton play = new JButton("play");
private JButton pause = new JButton("pause");

public Window(String titre) {

    this.setTitle(titre);
    this.setSize(900, 600);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Box b1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    b1.add(play);
    b1.add(pause);

    Box b2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    b2.add(b1);
    this.setContentPane(pan);
    this.getContentPane().add(b2);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.go();

}

private void go() {
    // Les coordonnées de départ de notre rond
    int x = pan.getPosX(), y = pan.getPosY();
    // Le booléen pour savoir si l'on recule ou non sur l'axe x
    boolean backX = false;
    // Le booléen pour savoir si l'on recule ou non sur l'axe y
    boolean backY = false;

    // Dans cet exemple, j'utilise une boucle while
    // Vous verrez qu'elle fonctionne très bien
    while (true) {
        // Si la coordonnée x est inférieure à 1, on avance
        if (x < 1)
            backX = false;

        // Si la coordonnée x est supérieure à la taille du Panneau moins la taille du
        // rond, on recule
        if (x > pan.getWidth() - 50)
            backX = true;

        // Idem pour l'axe y
        if (y < 1)
            backY = false;
        if (y > pan.getHeight() - 50)
            backY = true;

        // Si on avance, on incrémente la coordonnée
        // backX est un booléen, donc !backX revient à écrire
        // if (backX == false)
        if (!backX)
            pan.setPosX(++x);

        // Sinon, on décrémente
        else
            pan.setPosX(--x);

        // Idem pour l'axe Y
        if (!backY)
            pan.setPosY(++y);
        else
            pan.setPosY(--y);

        // On redessine notre Panneau
        pan.repaint();

        // Comme on dit : la pause s'impose ! Ici, trois millièmes de seconde
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

seconde class:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

private int posX = -50;
private int posY = -50;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(posX, posY, 50, 50);
}

public int getPosX() {
    return posX;
}

public void setPosX(int posX) {
    this.posX = posX;
}

public int getPosY() {
    return posY;
}

public void setPosY(int posY) {
    this.posY = posY;
}
}
```

and the main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class test {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Window window = new Window("Animation");

}

}
```

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas :)

Comment: It is probably some resource saver Linux has, if the Window is not active why waste resources drawing it?

Comment: well, I put high ressource with the monitor system and it does the same. Furthemore when I play minecraft it works well even if my mouse isn't over the window haha

Comment: I'd be wary that you `paintComponent` method is relying on properties which can be modified by another thread - if you want better control over the painting process, you should consider using a `BufferStrategy` instead

Comment: Yes, I'm a noob in java and even more in animation, i'm following this tuto but I'm only at the second week, I hope things will be more correct in a few weeks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling

> Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

After you do

> pan.repaint();

Comment: @DaniSanz That's a very broad question, start by having a look at the "[JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#sync--) - *"This method ensures that the display is up-to-date. It is useful for animation."*, I'd also recommend having a look at [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how the painting process actually works

Comment: There's a problem with linux's graphics scheduling meaning it gets slower and slower for some reason.
The call takes up precious CPU cycles (quite a lot of them, actually), so use System.getProperty("os.name") to determine if you need to use it.